# How to unmask netcdf in Python

Tags: python, netcdf

I am opening a NetCDF file in Python, as a file object. However, when I want to check the data and put the variables in a list, it shows that the values are masked! How do I unmask them?

The code I have is:

```
file = 'C:/Users/cru/0.5x0.5/pre/cru_ts3.23.2001.2010_.pre.dat.nc'
fileobj = netCDF4.Dataset(file)

tsvar = fileobj.variables[varname]
dec_list = []
dec_list.append(numpy.mean(tsvar[12,25,35]))
print dec_list
```

`tsvar` shape is: `(120, 360, 720) #(month, lat,lon)`

The output of printing `dec_list` is: `[masked]`. I see the same result for any month, lat or lon.

Comment: Can you post your code and what error message that you get?

Comment: Sure, this is the code: 

file = '/cru_ts3.23.2001.2010_.pre.dat.nc'
fileobj = netCDF4.Dataset(file)

tsvar = fileobj.variables[pre]
dec_list = []
#shape tsvar: (120, 360, 720)
dec_list.append(numpy.mean(tsvar[12,25,35]))
print dec_list

The error I get when I print dec_list is: [masked]
I get the same messagee to all the points and even when I want to calculate means, std, etc

Thanks!

Comment: Have You tried to look into the data with any other tool, "ncdump" etc? Could be that You have empty data file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about numpy masked arrays [numpy.ma](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/maskedarray.generic.html#what-is-a-masked-array)

```
if type(tsvar) ==  <class 'numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray'>
```

You can use numpy.ma.mean():

#instead of this
numpy.mean(tsvar[12,25,35])
# try
numpy.ma.mean(tsvar[12,25,35])

Answer (score 1):

netCDF4 load the data to masked array of numpy in default. The masked element is considered to be invalid for the data processing. Here is a good link for explanation: https://currents.soest.hawaii.edu/ocn760_4/_static/masked_arrays.html

Masked array may have different sum, mean and variance, you can check there is masked value in your array by:

```
print(np.where(tsvar.mask==True))
```

If you want to change the default set of loading in masked array, you can turn the mask operation off by:

```
for k in fileobj.variables:
      fileobj.variables[k].set_auto_mask(False)
```